# how to save documents in mongodb collection without timestamps

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime

please have a look at this date function

```
let tomorrowDate = new Date();
console.log('tomorrowDate',tomorrowDate ) // it returns D-1th date  
tomorrowDate = tomorrowDate.setDate(tomorrowDate.getDate() + 1);
tomorrowDate = new Date(tomorrowDate);
tomorrowDate = tomorrowDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
tomorrowDate = new Date(tomorrowDate);
```

I am facing an issue with this code if i do not restart my Dev server tomorrow picks up the D-1th date at 00:00hrs ,suppose today is 2020-03-11 at 00:00 hrs new Date should be 2020-03-12T...Z but at 00:00hrs new Date() returns 2020-03-11 why is that??? If i want to remove timestamp andjust want to save date i tried splitting T but this function still adds T00:00:00.000Z as timestamp.

Comment: I recommend to set default time zone for your server using this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/tzdata

Comment: I tested your code locally and it works

Comment: -Ahmed Kesha yes you are right but if you change your localhost time 00:00hrs and then test it without restarting the server then the mentioned issue come up

Comment: Why are you not using [moments.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), then it would be a simple `tomorrowDate = moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').toDate()` or `moment.utc().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').toDate()`

Comment: @-– Wernfried Domscheit thanks let me try that